# Init std::string with single copy

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring

I have the following code in C++ on Win32. It's simply a C++ warp on some Win32 API that returns  a `CHAR *`:

```
wstring expandEnvironmentVariables(const wstring & str)
{
    DWORD neededSize = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str.c_str(), nullptr, 0);
    vector<WCHAR> expandedStr(neededSize);
    if (0 == ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str.c_str(), expandedStr.data(), static_cast<DWORD>(expandedStr.size()))) {
        return wstring(str);
    }
    return wstring(expandedStr.data());
}
```

What bothers me about this code, is the double copy of the result.

1. by the API into a vector of `WCHAR`s.
2. from the vector into `std::wstring`.

Is there a way to implement this code with just a single copy, and without a major change to the signature of the function.
This is a specific example, but I'm more interested in the general solution and the right way to work with `std::wstring`/`std::string`, because this pattern shows itself in many places in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the C++ side you can just use a `wstring` directly as a result variable.

To get a pointer to the buffer of a `wstring` of non-zero size, just use `&s[0]`.

Just like `std::vector`, `std::basic_string` has a guaranteed contiguous buffer.

For the return it will probably get Return Value Optimization (RVO), and if not then it will be moved.

Disclaimer: I haven't checked the documentation of the API functions. I do not know if this code correct or even meaningful. I'm just assuming that.

Comment: @Angew: You're welcome. I was also certain until I once discovered the omission. It's weird.

Comment: I generally prefer `front` instead of `&s[0]`. It even works for containers like `list`.

Comment: But why would you want a pointer to the first node in a `list`?

Comment: Somewhere in generic code you could need that, maybe because you don't have the normal begin/end range.

Answer (score 3):

```
wstring expandEnvironmentVariables(const wstring & str)
{
    wstring expandedStr;
    DWORD neededSize = ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str.c_str(), 
                                                nullptr, 0);
    if (neededSize) 
    {
      expandedStr.resize(neededSize);
      if (0 == ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str.c_str(), 
                                        &expandedStr[0], 
                                        neededSize)) 
      {
          // pathological case requires a copy
          expandedStr = str;
      }
    }
    // RVO here
    return expandedStr;
}
```

EDIT:

On reflection, since we're using c++ let's go the whole hog and put in proper error detection and report errors with an informative nested exception chain:

```
DWORD check_not_zero(DWORD retval, const char* context)
{
  if(!retval)
      throw std::system_error(GetLastError(),
                              std::system_category(),
                              context);
    return retval;
}

std::wstring expandEnvironmentVariables(const std::wstring & str)
try
{
    DWORD neededSize = check_not_zero(ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str.c_str(),
                                                               nullptr,
                                                               0),
                                      "ExpandEnvironmentStrings1");

    std::wstring expandedStr(neededSize, 0);
    check_not_zero(ExpandEnvironmentStrings(str.c_str(),
                                            &expandedStr[0],
                                            neededSize),
                   "ExpandEnvironmentStrings2");

    // RVO here
    return expandedStr;
}
catch(...)
{
    std::throw_with_nested(std::runtime_error("expandEnvironmentVariables() failed"));
}
```

Comment: It would be prudent to check for 0 size. Expression `&s[0]` is UB for that size.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf rethought the error handling. Better to convert os errors to system_error in my view.

Comment: By defining function `fail` appropriately you can write that as `ExpandEnvironmentStrings( ... ) || fail( "message" )`. It's not so much used in C++ but is idiomatic in scripting languages. And I like it.

Comment: Agree. It's actually what I do in my own projects. It looks even nicer if you use the keyword "or" in place of "||"

Comment: According to cppreference.com. "Writing to the character array accessed through c_str() is undefined behavior."
I understand that it's probably ok, but it's not part of the standard.

Comment: @Pagefault that's why no part of this solution writes to the character array through c_str(). that would be impossible since c_str() is a const method.